# Allow explicit conversion of lambda System.Action to custom class without having to cast it

Tags: c#

A very quick disclaimer I am happy to be shot down if this is absolutely impossible or the solution is too inefficient. Also please note that this events / event example below is purely for demonstration purposes.

Say I have the class "Events" with a constructor that accepts an arbitrary amount of "Event" objects like so:

```
public class Events()
{
    public Events(params Event[] events)
    {
        // Handle each event object
    }
}
```

And the "Event" class simply takes a "System.Action" and runs it:

```
public class Event
{
    public Event(System.Action action)
    {
        // Invoke the action
    }
}
```

In this case, we could pass a bunch of "Event" objects into the "Events" constructor like so:

```
new Events(
    new Event(() => {/* Some action */}),
    new Event(() => {/* Some action */}),
    // etc
);
```

My question is simply, is there a way I could automatically get the "Events" construct to accept an Event directly as a System.Action / lambda expression like so:

```
new Events(
    () => {/* Some action */},
    () => {/* Some action */},
    new Event(() => {/* Some action */}), // With actual Event objects mixed in that have the potential to be far more complicated
    // etc
);
```

**What I have tried:**

Here is just a quick reminder that this is not anywhere near the exact thing I am using, but an example of how I am trying to handle the conversion.

Below is using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators reference here to add an explicit operator:

```
public class Event
{
    public Event(System.Action action)
    {
        // Invoke the action
    }
    
    // Handle conversion of System.Action to Event
    public static explicit operator Event(System.Action action) => new Event(() => {
        action.Invoke();
    });
}
```

This works, but *only* if I cast it like so:

```
new Events(
    (Event)(() => {/* Some action */})
);
```

If I do not cast it, I get an error similar to:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Event' because it is not a
> delegate type

Is there any way to get C# to automatically realise that a lambda System.Action can automatically be recognised as an Event? Or should I always cast it?

**Final notes:**

- I realise I am only asking to save a few characters, but as in my case I would be writing literally thousands of these I am just making sure before I go ahead A. whether this is even possible, and B. If it is possible, is it going to be so inefficient that it makes too big an impact.
- Maybe I have misunderstood the difference between implicit and explicit in this situation, I can't seem to figure out whether in this case, I should actually be extending "System.Action" instead and adding an implicit conversion to my object, or the other way around.

Thanks in advance for any advice on the subject!

Comment: What extra functionality is `Event` going to have that `Action` doesn't? Have you considered implementing those functionalities using extension methods?

Comment: Honestly in my case it has 100's of extra functionalities, but the most basic version of Event could be just an action also, and these are also quite common. It is hard to explain without showing my exact use case so I tried to keep the example as generic as possible. But yes, Event does have much more going on behind the scenes.

Comment: And yes I have extension methods also, this is more of a question to do with whether this automatic conversion is actually possible / viable. Sorry if my original question isn't making this very obvious.

Comment: This may explain why your explicit/implicit operators don't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916820/implicit-conversion-from-lambda-expression-to-user-defined-type

Comment: @Artur ah ok thanks so it's really because a `lamda` doesn't have a `type` as such! Interesting. I was wondering this because on the dotnet page I shared on the subject it seemed to work one way without type casting, but it did the other. But if lambda isn't a type at all then I guess this is impossible either way.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a constructor to `Events` that takes an array of actions. It can then construct the Event objects. Something like this:

```
public Events(params System.Action actions[]) {
    var events = new List<Event>(actions.Length);
    foreach (var action in actions) {
        events.Add(new Event(action));
    }

    // load events array like you do in the normal constructor
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. In my case, I would need to be able to mix an "Event" object alongside "Action"s that are converted to "Event" objects. I have updated my question to represent this. I understand that it seems like an "Event" object is very simple and just calls an action but in my case it is far more complicated than this, so I'm just using this as an example to find out whether this conversion is possible. Hope this makes some sense.

Comment: Then the answer is no, you can't do it. In a language with union types like TypeScript you could make a function that takes an array of  `System.Action | Event`, and you could specify either one. Such mixing of otherwise unrelated types is not possible in C#.

Comment: Ah OK I see, maybe my question was beating around the bush too much. So if it is only possible when an object with an explicit operator conversion is manually type casted, I am probably better off just doing it the way I am and passing all basic events directly as new objects. It's hard to explain why this is annoying without showing my entire project but at least this answers whether it is possible or not. Thanks again!

Comment: @Zephni C#, while having some sugar, is still somewhat in the mold of Java in that it does often require a lot of boilerplate. This is one of those times. If you really want terse and implicit, you could use F# or Haskell or some other FP language that has more powerful constructs for this sort of thing (and beyond).